# How to copy UV coordinates between similarly-shaped surfaces?

Tags: mesh, uv, faces, texture-coordinates

At first I'd like to say that I'm quite new to 3D modelling so I'm sorry if the question might be silly..

I have two simillarly shaped (but not identical) mesh objects: mesh A and mesh B. They have different amount of triangles and vertices.

My goal is to make the mesh B using textures for mesh A. So I need to make mesh B having compatibile UV map.

I tried using Transfer Mesh Data tool with UV option but the results aren't that great.

So to achieve my goal I would like to select some faces from mesh B, then select matching faces of mesh A and make blender automaticly adjust the UV coordinates of selected faces on mesh B to match faces on mesh A.

And here is my question - how could I make the blender do it? Or if it doesn't have this functionality maybe there is (even paid) some blender addon that could do that?

Thank you in advance for help! <3

Answer (score 2):

You can use a data transfer modifier to copy UV from one mesh to another.  There are a variety of mapping options; "nearest face interpolated" is probably the best for your purposes:

[image]

Don't forget to hit "generate data layers" to create the UV maps on the modified mesh if they do not already exist.

However, this isn't a good way to achieve what you want.  A data transfer of UV is something that cannot be perfect: what if the seam between two UV islands runs through a face on the modified mesh?  Your face will span the islands; if you try to fix that, you'll find that now your face includes undetailed parts of your texture.

A better technique to achieve what you want is to use selected-to-active texture baking, to bake the texture from one mesh onto the existing UV of another mesh.  I'm not willing to provide a full accounting of texture baking in this answer, but there are a great number of resources and tutorials regarding the technique, including many questions and answers on this site, and I don't think you'll have any trouble finding more information now that you know what to look for.  Sometimes, "selected-to-active" baking is referred to as "high-to-low" baking, because it is often used to bake normals from a high poly mesh to a low poly mesh, but there is no reason that the objects involved have to be high or low poly, or even have any particular relationship to each other whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. Sadly the mesh object I generate will be for the game where there are already ready textures. Those textures won't be possible to be modified - simply new object has to accept already existing textures for mesh A. So I understand that the only way to copy UVs is using data transfer tool? it's impossible to make this process partly manual (for example selecting faces with seams and so on to achieve more exact result) ? I don't mind if this process isn't fully automatic and is slow. I just need it to be done as perfectly as it is possible.

Comment: @AmaeSaeki You can make it as manual as you want-- you could data transfer, apply, then edit UV-- but it's just inherently not a perfect technique.  Being careful with *modelling* a mesh, making sure source seams are aligned with destination edges as much as possible, will help a lot though.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will see what I can do with it! I need 4 more rep to give upvotes otherwise i would already give your answer one <3